# How can i convert a Model.Tag (has Id and Name) to a "List of" Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public List<string> TagNameList (int objectId)
{
    List<string> tagNameList = db.Tags.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId).ToList();  
}

db.Tags.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId).ToList();
```

I'm going into the `db` context in the `Tags` and i select all the tags that have a set `objectId` via a navigation property i have setup through an `ObjectTags` table that stores the relationships in two columns, both make up a composite key.

The sample returns an `IQueryable<app.Models.Tag>`. Is there any quick way to convert this to a `List<string>` with just the `Tag.Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to a good friend.

```
db.Objects.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId).First().Tags.Select(t => t.TagName).ToList()
```

The **First()** was essential to "narrow" it down to one object and then navigate to the other table.

This is SO COOL. You could navigate to tens of tables like this. I wonder if you can write the longest line of code this way :D

Answer (score 5):

Yup, you just need to apply a projection using `Select`:

```
public List<string> TagNameList (int objectId)
{
    return db.Tags.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId)
                  .Select(tag => tag.Name)
                  .ToList();  
}
```

EDIT: Okay, given your update, you can use `First()` if you only want the first object from each collection - if you want the name from *each* object in the collection, you could use `SelectMany`:

```
public List<string> TagNameList (int objectId)
{
    return db.Tags.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId)
                  .SelectMany(ob => ob.Tags)
                  .Select(tag => tag.Name)
                  .ToList();  
}
```

Comment: Not so fast... :) I have a relationships table with multiple ObjectIds and multiple TagIds. I can't access the relationships table directly, since it does not appear in ADO.net. I can only access it via the Objects table. Something like this db.Objects.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId).Select(t => t.Tags) I am going into the Objects table and narrowing it down, then selecting stuff in the Tags table. Now i have a bunch of EntityCollection<Models.Tags>. How do i convert these to a list or something usable in the model i pass to the view?

Comment: Edited with more information: I have a relationships table with multiple ObjectIds and multiple TagIds. I can't access the relationships table directly, since it does not appear in ADO.net. I can only access it via the Objects table. Something like this db.Objects.Where(ob => ob.Id == objectId).Select(t => t.Tags) I am going into the Objects table and narrowing it down, then selecting stuff in the Tags table. Now i have a bunch of ...IQueryable<...DataClasses.EntityCollection<Models.Tags>. How do i convert these to a list or something usable in the model i pass to the view?